# How (re)sampling from my custom probability mass function with Edward or TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, edward

I collected some data, draw a histogram and did statical estimation using kernel density estimation, so I got my custom probability mass function.
But I cannot resample from the function.

So, it is estimable P(X=x) but cannot resample x ~ P(x).

How (re)sampling from my custom probability mass function with Edward or TensorFlow?